# I would like to know default oracle view for country name/nationality?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to know if there is any default oracle view for all Country name/Nationality which we can use for dropdown list of oracle apex application after giving access to application schema.

Your suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You'll have to create your own. However, in apex that should be a breeze. Copy and paste the list of countries from any wiki in an excel file (or download from [here](https://copylists.com/geography/list-all-countries/)) and use the data workshop to load it into a table.

Answer (score 1):

right now, there is no default view for country list, you need to maintainer separate table for country_list,Just download the common [country list](https://www.iban.com/country-codes) and import into your table, which the most helpful, even if required any column in future, you can add additionally.